# JQuery don't change the value of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a problem with JQuery & HTML.
I'm working on Wordpress 3.8.1, so my code is split up.

I've got this input (in sidebar.php):

```
    <input type="hidden" name="lg" value=" ">
```

This input value needs to change when a option has been choosen from a select.

The select code is (in header.php):

```
    <select class="langbox" name="lang" onChange="url_redirect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option >Language</option>
        <option class="text-option" value="it">Italiano</option>
        <option class="text-option" value="en">English</option>
        <option class="text-option" value="de">Deutsch</option>
        <option class="text-option" value="fr">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
        <option class="text-option" value="ru">Pусский</option>
    </select>
```

This is my function url_redirect():

```
    function url_redirect(lang){
        alert($('input[name="lg"]').val());
        $('input[name="lg"]').val(lang);
        alert($('input[name="lg"]').val());
        window.location='http://www.myurl.com/'+lang;}
```

The first alert shows me that the value is " ", the second alert shows me the correct result (de, it, fr, en, ru), but the value of the input doesn't change, and I don't know why. I've tried everything but nothing works. The reason could be that the code is split in different files .php as wordpress needs? JS error?

P.S: the window.location works.

Comment: You say the window.location works, which means you are being redirected from the page, correct? So, what does it matter what the page shows for the half-second before it changes?

Comment: The alert are only for testing the results.

Comment: Comment out the `window.location` line. Does the input field change value then?

Comment: Why would you use inline JS in Wordpress? Use proper event handlers wrapped in no-conflict DOM ready handler, as explained in the Wordpress Codex, and you'll be fine.

Comment: And what would be the point of changing the inputs value just to redirect the page ?

Comment: "but the value of the input doesn't change" How do you check it??? Because "the second alert shows me the correct result ", so value changed

Comment: If you get a redirect simply you'll get a new page that has a fresh new <select> and so no option it's selected. You can pass the value by url, use an ajax call or something like that to assign a "selected" attribute to right option.
However be careful with infinite loop due to trigger of onChange

Comment: Commenting the windows.location it works, but i Need that the page in which I redirect has the value I set in the current page.

Comment: @AndreaGiachetto What an unclear question then. You should have told about it earlier. Redirecting to new page make reset all non persistent data, that's how works the web. So use persistent data client side as cookie/local storage or session storage or set data server side

Comment: When the page redirects it's reloading the `<input />` so it's value will always be blank, unless, as others have suggested you pass the value via url or localCache or sessionCache or something similar to save the value

Comment: So I will use the cookies. Thank you everybody!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cookie and set value to select,you can use jquery cookie plugin i think cookie functions is deprecate from jquery library

```
function url_redirect(lang){
  $.cookie("selectindex",lang);
    alert($('select[name="lang"]').val());
    $('select[name="lang"]').val(lang);
    alert($('select[name="lang"]').val());
    window.location='http://www.myurl.com/'+lang;
 }

 if($.cookie("selectindex") !== undefined){
 $('select[name="lang"]').val($.cookie("selectindex"));
 }
```